# Magento2 Product Import - Select / Multiselect Field values do not work

Tags: magento2

i try to add the value of an custom select and multiselect attribute in my custom product import job. But it do not work.

F.e. I have a custom SELECT attribute "pattern" with values (A,B,C), than i try to add the related product value in my import:

```
...
$oSimpleProduct = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

// ... add the min req. attributes

// HERE is my problem ... $oProductItem->getPattern() has value "A"
$oSimpleProduct->setCustomAttribute('pattern', $oProductItem->getPattern());

$oSimpleProduct->save();

...
```

After the save the product shows up in the magento admin .. but the field is still empty. If i load the product field it shows:

```
object(Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue)#3969 (1) {
  ["_data":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    ["attribute_code"]=>
    string(7) "pattern"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Do anyone know what i am doing wrong? - How can i add SELECT AND MULTISELECT Values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok .. i found a solution as i am oriented me at magento 1 ..

My Solution ( ONLY AN EXAMPLE )!!! :

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config as EavConfig;

/**
 * Class Import
 * @package Foo\Bar\Console\Command
 */
class Import extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var EavConfig
     */
    protected $_eavConfig;

    /**
     * Foo constructor.
     * @param EavConfig $eavConfig
     */
    public function __construct(EavConfig $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->_eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent::__construct('foo:import_products');
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('foo:import_products')->setDescription('Full import of foo product xml');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        // ....
        $sValueKey = $this->_getOptionValueId('pattern', $oProductItem->getPattern());

        if ($sValueKey) {
            $oSimpleProduct->setCustomAttribute('pattern', $sValueKey);
        } else {
            // LOG .. OR SOMETHING
        }
        // ....

    }

    /**
     * @param $attributeCode
     * @param $searchValue
     * @return bool|string
     */
    protected function _getOptionValueId($attributeCode, $searchValue)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $oAttribute */
        $oAttribute = $this->_loadAttribute($attributeCode);
        if (!$oAttribute) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($oAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            if (strtoupper($option['label']) == strtoupper($searchValue)) {
                return $option['value'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $attributeCode
     * @return bool|Attribute
     */
    protected function _loadAttribute($attributeCode)
    {
        /** @var Attribute $attribute */
        $oAttribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product',$attributeCode);
        if (!$oAttribute->getId()) {
            return false;
        }
        return $oAttribute;
    }

}
```